# Varying modal verbs in counterfactual ("subjunctive") conditionals

Tags: conditionals, modal-verbs, subjunctive-mood

There are some situations in which one would like to vary the modal verb in counterfactual conditionals, but it seems to be incorrect.

1. "If things were otherwise, she **would** keep her promise."
   This seems like perfectly ordinary usage.
2. "If things were otherwise, she **might** keep her promise."
   This also sounds fine.
3. "If things were otherwise, she **must** keep her promise."
   This sounds wrong. But there is an obvious alternative: "If things were otherwise, she **would have to** keep her promise."
4. "If things were otherwise, she **should** keep her promise."
   This also sounds kind of bad. But I can't think of an alternative way to convey this thought without bending over backwards. (Maybe "If things were otherwise, she ought to keep her promise," sounds better, but the issue seems to be the same. And "ought" often sounds too formal to my ear.)

My specific question is: Is sentence 4 necessarily incorrect? And if so, is there a better way to convey its thought?

More generally: is it ok to vary the modal verbs in counterfactual conditionals, as in examples 3 and 4?

Comment: For (4), you can use *she would be obligated to keep her promise..*

Comment: If things were otherwise, she *would have to keep* her promise.

Comment: 4 sounds OK, although I'm not sure if it implies probability or obligation. The use of modals is so complex I don't think any linguist would be confident that they understood every case.

Comment: All four sentences are idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

Briefly, and without repeating commonplace definitions of *would* and *should*.

As a consequence of things being otherwise:

She would = the promise is kept

She might = there is a possibility that the promise is kept

She must = tries to use must in subjunctive form, which is not appropriate. See [Can I use the word "must" in subjunctive mood?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/119663/can-i-use-the-word-must-in-subjunctive-mood)

She would have to = she is compelled to keep it

She should = she is obliged to keep it but there is a possibility she does not

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but this doesn't clearly answer either of my questions. "tries to use must in subjunctive form, which is not appropriate" comes close to answering, but the link you shared seems to be about an importantly disanalogous grammatical situation.

Comment: "must" does not have a subjunctive form....

Comment: There is no "subjunctive form" in English. There are a couple of constructions (untensed _that_-complement clauses, like _He demanded that she obey/*obeys him_; and irrealis past usages like _Wish you were/*are here_) that various people sometimes call "subjunctive", but they don't agree, so it's better  to simply not mention the term; it only upsets them. In any event, modals are not subjunctive, though they have meanings that are similar to subjunctives in other languages.

Comment: @JohnLawler I believe you are too prescriptive on this one. Collins, for example has "*The subjunctive was formerly used in English for situations that were improbable or that expressed a wish. It is only rarely used in modern British English. It is, however, found in certain set phrases and in very formal forms of speech and writing.*", and EnglishCLub has "*The English subjunctive is a special, relatively rare verb form that expresses something desired or imagined.*". There are other examples.

Comment: Oh, there was subjunctive in Old English, and in some dialects of Middle English (and maybe some current local dialects -- I wouldn't know). But all there is now in Modern English is a bunch of set phrases and ritual proscriptions. If you want to call them all "subjunctive", no problemo. But it doesn't mean anything; and "subjunctive" in English is not a "form", but an imaginary inflection.